# How can you add a transition to .class:not(:hover)?

Tags: html, css, sass, hover, gallery

I've been working on a hover gallery where once one of the elements is hovered, it grows to the size of the whole gallery while everything else is set to opacity: 0 and height: 0. Adding a transition anywhere in its class or the gallery-wrap doesn't work and has no effect whatsoever. In which class do I have to put it in so it will work as intended?

I've tried putting in transition: 10s but it hasn't worked anywhere so far.

```
HTML:

          <div class="gallery-wrap">
            <div class="gallery-item" style="--n: 0">
              <div style="background-image: url(assets/images/first.jpg);" class="gallery-part"></div>
              <p>First</p>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-item" style="--n: 1">
              <div style="background-image: url(assets/images/second.JPG);" class="gallery-part"></div>
              <p>Second</p>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-item" style="--n: 2">
              <div style="background-image: url(assets/images/third.jpeg);" class="gallery-part"></div>
              <p>Thir</p>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-item" style="--n: 3">
              <div style="background-image: url(assets/images/fourth.jpg);" class="gallery-part"></div>
              <p>Fourth</p>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-item" style="--n: 4">
              <div style="background-image: url(assets/images/fifth.jpg);" class="gallery-part"></div>
              <p>Fifth</p>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-item" style="--n: 5">
              <div style="background-image: url(assets/images/sixth.jpg); --n: 5" class="gallery-part"></div>
              <p>Sixth</p>
            </div>
          </div>

SCSS:

.gallery-wrap{
  width: 28vw;
  height: 48vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  .gallery-part{
    transition: .8s;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 8vh;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: .1;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0) 250%);
  }
  p{
    padding-left: 2%;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 0;
    transform: translateY(-8vh);
  }
  &:hover{
    > .gallery-item:not(:hover){
      opacity: 0;
      height: 0;
    }
    > .gallery-item{
      &:hover{
        height: 48vh;
      }
    }
  }
}

.gallery-item{
  &:hover{
    height: 0;
    > .gallery-part{
      opacity: 1;
      height: 48vh;
      filter: none;
    }
  }
}
```

It should be a smooth transition and not a jumping transition. So the height of all gallery-items but the one being hovered should move slowly to 0 whilst the hovered element should grow to the size of the gallery wrap.
Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.gallery-item` elements jumps from an unspecified height to `height: 0;` without any transition.

So if you modify your `.gallery-item` selector slightly, you should get what you want:

```
.gallery-item {
    height: 8vh; /* New */
    transition: 0.8s; /* New */

  &:hover {
    height: 0;

    > .gallery-part {
      opacity: 1;
      height: 48vh;
      filter: none;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You just made my day! Worked perfectly fine.